# CSS: Image scaling issue with flexbox in Firefox/Internet Explorer

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to place two images side by side in my content flow. In Chrome/Safari it scales the images properly, but in Firefox/IE the aspect ratio is not respected and the images are distorted. The overall width of the content flow depends on the width of the browser. The images therefor needs to readjust as the window gets narrower.

This is how it looks in Chrome/Safari (WebKit):

[Aspect ratio respected http://pluto.justdied.com/w2box/data/chrome.PNG](http://pluto.justdied.com/w2box/data/chrome.PNG)

While this is how it looks in Firefox/Internet Explorer:

[image stretches http://pluto.justdied.com/w2box/data/exhibit.PNG](http://pluto.justdied.com/w2box/data/exhibit.PNG)

This 2 column view comes in a long line of images.

The HTML markup:

```
<div class="grid">
  <img src="../images/mille_bornes_02.jpg">
  <img src="../images/mille_bornes_08.jpg">
</div>
```

And the CSS is as follows:

```
.grid {
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0px 0px 16.5px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.grid img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 16.5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid > img:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

I've tried to fiddle with the sizing, but I still end up with some form of distortion in Firefox/IE. Any ideas about how I can fix it? My hope was to use flexbox to avoid having to brute force it with JavaScript.

Both the source images share the same height and width.

All feedback and help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: your code is fine, but height auto in .grid may be the issue in FF. this looks ok in FF -- https://jsfiddle.net/12dn6wbe/ -- you may need to specify pixels instead

Comment: Unfortunately the images in your jsfiddle get distorted when the width of the browser/window is reduced.

Comment: yeah i just saw that, give me a sec ill give you a better solution

Comment: there you go. i divided the screen into 2 boxes of equal h/w and changed the css for the images to contain. if it works for you ill put it as  answer -- https://jsfiddle.net/wkpnygdb/  -- hold on thats spooky. the demo works fine in FF but not in Chrome. Odd

Comment: there you go, a solution that works in all browsers. -- https://jsfiddle.net/kd2qntbv/

Comment: another cross browser solution is to use css background instead of img tags to contain them perfectly -- https://jsfiddle.net/dapspxev/

Comment: Thank you for your input, but these solutions don't seem to respect the fixed margin between the images and appear inconsistent depending on the window width. I've added a pure JS "solution" in lack of a CSS solution below.

Answer (score 7):

wrap your img's in a block level element. (I just had this exact same issue)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="../images/mille_bornes_02.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="../images/mille_bornes_08.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

and your css should target the `<div>` not the `<img />`

Comment: In my case, I used a `<div>` as the wrapper/flex and then `<figure><img /></figure>`

Answer (score 5):

I haven't looked into your specific situation much, but I came across your question while trying to solve a similar problem where images inside a flex container were skewed on Firefox.

My solution was to add `object-fit: contain` to the images and that fixed the aspect ratio in FF.

Better late than never if it helps!

Comment: This just helped me fix the same issue as yours, same scenario as yours. Tks for sharing! One can find more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find a good cross-browser supported CSS solution I've made the following JavaScript function that can be fired as the page loads and when the window/browser is resized:

```
function adjustGrids() {
  var margin = 16.5;
  var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
  var gridWidth = grid[0].offsetWidth;

  for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    var images = grid[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var y = 0; y < images.length; y++) {
      images[y].style.width = ((gridWidth - margin) / 2) + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

This solution respects the fixed margin between the images, and loops through all similar "grids" on the page.

If anyone has a better solution I'm all ears!